# IronPythonConsole C# variable scope

Tags: c#, ironpython

I created an application that should process a Python script, using IronPythonConsoleControl control. I´d like to access some C# defined dictionaries from inside python script. So, I did:

```
    ...

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> envPrm = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        PythonConsoleControl.IronPythonConsoleControl pythonConsole = null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            pythonConsole = new PythonConsoleControl.IronPythonConsoleControl();
            pythonConsole.Pad.Host.ConsoleCreated += new PythonConsoleControl.ConsoleCreatedEventHandler(Host_ConsoleCreated);
        }

        void Console_ConsoleInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pythonConsole.Pad.Console.ScriptScope.SetVariable("envprm", envPrm);
        }

        void Host_ConsoleCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pythonConsole.Pad.Console.ConsoleInitialized += new PythonConsoleControl.ConsoleInitializedEventHandler(Console_ConsoleInitialized);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ehConsole.Child = pythonConsole;
            envPrm.Add("a", "Mauro");
            envPrm.Add("b", "Bete");
        }

        private void RunScript(string script)
        {

            ScriptSource scriptSource = pythonConsole.Pad.Console.ScriptScope.Engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(script, SourceCodeKind.Statements);

            try
            {
                scriptSource.Execute();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Error processing initializing script. Message: {0}\r\n, Script: {1}", ex.Message, script));
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RunScript(textBox1.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I run some script that references the envprm variable, the IronPython engine doesn´t knows about that. However, when I run some instructions that references the variable at the console, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

What is, if you execute the code like this:

```
public dynamic Execute(string Expression)
{
    return scriptEngine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(Expression).Execute(scriptScope);
}
```

This works for me very well.

Comment: Would you like to set it as answered?